# Pass file attributes/properties/metadata in form upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an html form with an input file where user can upload files to my server. When the file arrives in my PHP I can only access file name and content. Is it possible to have access to file attributes/properties or metadata? Like, last modified date, creation date, folder path, owner...?

If it's not possible using PHP (I believe it's not cause when I debug the request there is no information like that being sent to the server) is it possible to have access to these information using JS?

Comment: I don't think Javascript has any access to information about the file being uploaded, for security reasons.

Comment: @Barmar I believe so but I would like to be more sure about that. I hope someone can answer this cause in Google I could not find any thing.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of files you upload. If is a text file(.txt), it haven't metadata.
You can go to the PHP main page, there are some info about $_FILES
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php